# Convert 2 lists into a dictionary using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 lists which i want to convert to a dictionary using dictionary comprehension.

```
aa = ['07:51:59', '07:53:35', '07:55:20', '08:01:48']
bb = [50769054, 183926374, 183926374, 183926374]
```

Output should be like:

```
{50769054:['07:51:59'], 183926374:['07:53:35', '07:55:20', '08:01:48']}
```

I am trying this way:

```
dictionary ={}
{bb[k]:aa[k] if bb[k] not in dictionary.keys() else dictionary[bb[k]].append(aa[k]) for k in range(0,4)}
```

But it is giving me single values only.
My output:

```
{50769054: ['07:51:59'], 183926374: ['08:01:48']}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be in a comprehension? This is not a good use case for it.

Comment: I agree with @kabanus , your code does not work because the comprehension is not modifying your dictionary incrementally but rather returning a shallow copy. Your if condition always returns true because you never create the keys (until the very end) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, `defaultict` with `zip`

```
from collections import defaultdict

aa = ['07:51:59', '07:53:35', '07:55:20', '08:01:48']
bb = [50769054, 183926374, 183926374, 183926374]

result = defaultdict(list)

for x, y in zip(aa, bb):
    result[y].append(x)
```

---

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {50769054: ['07:51:59'], 183926374: ['07:53:35', '07:55:20', '08:01:48']})
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sushanth's solution is accurate. In that extend, you can use comprehension like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

aa = ['07:51:59', '07:53:35', '07:55:20', '08:01:48']
bb = [50769054, 183926374, 183926374, 183926374]

dictionary = defaultdict(list)
[dictionary[y].append(x) for x, y in zip(aa, bb)]

print(dict(dictionary))
```

**Output:**

```
{50769054: ['07:51:59'], 183926374: ['07:53:35', '07:55:20', '08:01:48']}
```